# Remove Scrollbar from iFrame

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, iframe, modern-pages, script-webpart

I have used an iframe in my classic sp page this is referencing a modern sp site but it is has a vertical scroll bar. I have tried to override it with some css and it hasnt appeared to go away.

How can this be removed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the script below to display specific area of a page using iframe:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 575px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://<path>" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -36px; margin-top: -486px; width: 650px; height: 812px; ">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Notice the overflow and margin attributes.

move the iframe left, set margin-left; move iframe top, set margin-top.

Demo:

http://www.dimpost.com/2012/12/iframe-how-to-display-specific-part-of.html

Comment: Hi I tried to use the similar script but unfortunately the bar doesn't disappear.  <div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 575px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://bp365.sharepoint.com/sites/COP/DataScience/SitePages/CoP-Leadership-Team.aspx" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 36px; margin-top: 30px; width: 450px; height: 512px; ">
</iframe>
</div>